# Some files are not added from the branch during merging the conflicts with master in git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have 3 folders and each folder contains 2 files in a branch I tried to merge this branch with the master.

I have used the `git merge origin/branch` name command for the merging process. Few are merged with the master like one complete folder and a file from the second folder. A file from the second folder and the complete third folder is missing. Why is this happening?

Comment: Were there any *merge conflicts* during the `git merge` process that you ignored?

Comment: No, it just showed only 3 files during the conflict when I give "git merge origin/branch" out of 6 files

Comment: And this 3 files you solve manually? And now where are the files missing? In `master` branch?

Comment: Let me explain clearly I had three folders in a branch and each folder has a js file and a CSS file total of 6 files. when I used the "git merge origin/branch " command.  What I expected to happen is that all three folders with a total of six files should be ready to merge with the master so I can resolve the conflicts and push the code. Instead, a folder and a file from another folder alone get pulled when I gave the merge command other three files got ingnored.

Comment: But maybe ignoring is correct because there were no changes or changes that were automatically merged. Or have you already *change* ALL 6 files?

Comment: I created a pull request through the bit bucket dashboard the result is the same it  Only merges the three files. If ignoring those files is correct but after the merge, I checked the repository for those files that the merge skipped are missing in the repository too

Comment: For my understanding: Those missing files are currently - after merging - not available on the *destination* merging branch, as if the files had been deleted?

Comment: can you explain more detailed?